# How to select only the first 10 rows in my AWK script

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a large CSV file. Basically what I want to do is display only the first 5 columns (which I can) but I also only want to display the first 10 rows, which is what I can't figure out. Right now this is the .awk file script I have:

```
"BEGIN {FS = ","}
{print $1", " $2", " $3", " $4", " $5}"
```

In Tera Term this is the command I use, which results in the first 5 columns of every row to be displayed:
$awk -f example.awk example.csv

I have tried a couple of ways of using NR<=11 but that keeps coming up with error messages when trying to run on Tera Term.

Please help!

Comment: You can use `awk something | head -n 10`

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5} NR==10{exit}' OFS=', ' file.csv
```

[Note that the awk code is in **single**-quotes, not double-quotes.  That is necessary to prevent the shell from misinterpreting `$1`, etc., as shell variables and expanding them.]

#### How it works

- `-F,` tells awk to use `,` as the field separator on input. This is equivalent to but much briefer than `BEGIN {FS = ","}`.
- `print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5` tells awk to print the first five columns.  (See below for why the `", "` strings aren't needed in this version.)
- `NR==10{exit}` tells awk to exit on the tenth line.
- `OFS=', '` tells awk to use comma-space as the field separator on output.  This setting makes much of the quoting in the original code unnecessary.

Comment: Oh you are a legend! The NR==10{exit} worked a treat and OFS=', ' is so much simpler. Thank you so much!

Comment: @lonewolf2288 : `NR==FNR` is, also, something you would frequently use especially when processing fwo files simultaneously with awk. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[awk]+%22NR%3D%3DFNR%22).

Comment: @John1024, the code works, but ends with a `,` after the last record (e.g. `1,2,3,4,`). Is that expected? Is there a way to get rid of that `,` in `awk`? (I know I could pipe to `sed 's/,$//'`)

Comment: @Josh I can't reproduce that problem.  Just some thoughts:  Is it possible that your fifth column is empty? Or, does the source file contain strange characters?  Was the source file edited on Windows?  You might find something peculiar in the file if you run it through a hex dump (If you have `od` installed, try `od -c file.csv | head`).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively,

```
awk -F, 'NR==1, NR==10 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' OFS=', ' file.csv
```

This solution has the slight advantage that it also works for ranges that do not start with the first line, e.g. `NR==21, NR==35`.